# MATLAB - ball structuring element

Tags: matlab

Is the `ball` structuring element mentioned [here](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/strel.html#bqkf9ju) the same as the `rolling ball` structuring element? Are they two names to the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In [this example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) that refers to a "rolling ball" strel; it's created with `se = strel('ball',5,5);`. This is exactly the same as `ball` in the man page for `strel` itself.